# Possible to patch a mysql sql file without using phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, merge, patch

If I have a cms, shopping cart, or some db based web script and lets say it has a database with like 50 tables

If I have a .sql file (call it patch.sql) that has a few ALTER commands and some UPDATE commands, I can goto phpmyadmin, import the patch.sql file and it will "apply" the changes to my db.

But lets say I export my db to a mydb.sql file first
Is there a way to "apply" the changes from "patch.sql" to "mydb.sql" without using a database?

I figured some command line like

```
mysql.exe merge patch.sql mydb.sql
```

or something but I didn't see anything like that.

Is phpmyadmin with a database the only way?

Comment: Delete the useless line from the mydb.sql file?

Comment: That doesn't apply to anything I said.

Comment: Indeed yes. You want to use the update on the file mydb.sql to the database in patch.sql. Just delete the command you don't need and use phpmyadmin to import.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa  This quickly becomes non-trivial, as there's usually not anything to delete, but stuff to change. If your updates to the database adds 50 columns to 20 tables, changes the column type of 20 columns in 10 tables, adds 15 new indexes to existing tables and so on, you got yourself quite some work hand-merging that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to be able to later reimport mydb.sql and get the patched version of the database, then no, there are no tools to do that. patch.sql may has altered the structure of the database as well as the data itself based on your description. What you should do is apply the patch to your database, then export your db to a new .sql file.

Comment: Yea, ok that is what I've been doing and what I thought. Thanks for confirming :)